# Fedex ShipService shipping Label Printing

Tags: api, printing, fedex

I'm working on a web application (C# MVC) that needs to print a FEDEX shipping label. I could get raw label data for the printer in ZPL via the fedex API.

I just don't know how to send that data to the printer through .NET  (C#). The data is in ZPL format I just need to send it to the printer. My printer is Zebra ZT230. This is printing from the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can send your ZPL code as RAW data to your ZT230 printer, bypassing the driver

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/138594/howto-send-raw-data-to-a-printer-by-using-the-win32-api

2) Or install your ZT230 with a driver call "Generic/Text Only" and print.